# Yocto. How to keep u-boot splash screen and then how to keep kernel splash screen on

Tags: linux, kernel, yocto, u-boot, display-settings

I am porting Yocto into my board. I wrote u-boot & kernel graphics drivers for my display. Everything works fine. The only problem I have is:

- u-boot splash screen is displayed for a while when kernel starts to
  load the screen goes blank
- then the kernel splash screen appears for a while, but the screen
  goes blank until Weston is loaded.

Is it possible to prevent the screen from going blank?